# Create multiple confusion matrices in R using loops

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, confusion-matrix

I am trying to create multiple confusion matrices from one dataframe, with each matrix generated based off a different condition in the dataframe.

So for the dataframe below, I want a confusion matrix for when `Value = 1`, `Value = 2`, `Value =3`

```r
  observed predicted Value
       1      1      1
       0      1      1
       1      0      2
       0      0      2
       1      1      3
       0      0      3
```

and see the results like:

```r
Value  Sensitivity  Specificity  PPV  NPV
1        .96            .71      .84  .95
2        .89            .63      .30  .45     
3        .88            .95      .28  .80
```

This is what I tried with a reproducible example. I am trying to write a loop that looks at every row, determines if `Age = 1`, and then pulls the values from the predicted and observed columns to generate a confusion matrix. Then I manually pull out the values from the confusion matrix to write out sen, spec, ppv, and npv and tried to combine all the matrices together. And then the loop starts again with `Age = 2`.

```r
data(scat)
df<-scat %>% transmute(observed=ifelse(Site=="YOLA","case", "control"), predicted=ifelse(Location=="edge","case", "control"),Age)

x<-1 #evaluate at ages 1 through 5
for (i in dim(df)[1]) { #for every row in df
  while(x<6) { #loop stops at Age=5
    if(x=df$Age) {
      q<-confusionMatrix(data = df$predicted, reference = df$observed, positive = "case")
      sensitivity = q$table[1,1]/(q$table[1,1]+q$table[2,1])
      specificity = q$table[2,2]/(q$table[2,2]+q$table[1,2])
      ppv = q$table[1,1]/(q$table[1,1]+q$table[1,2])
      npv = q$table[2,2]/(q$table[2,2]+q$table[2,1])
      matrix(c(sensitivity, specificity, ppv, npv),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)
    }
  }
  x <- x + 1 #confusion matrix at next Age value
}

final<- rbind(matrix) #combine all the matrices together
```

However, this loop is completely non-functional. I'm not sure where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified and the desired output achieved like this:

```r
library(caret)
library(dplyr)

data(scat)

df <- scat %>% 
  transmute(observed = factor(ifelse(Site == "YOLA","case", "control")), 
            predicted = factor(ifelse(Location == "edge","case", "control")),
            Age)

final <- t(sapply(sort(unique(df$Age)), function(i) { 
  
  q <- confusionMatrix(data      = df$predicted[df$Age == i],
                       reference = df$observed[df$Age == i], 
                       positive  = "case")$table
  
  c(sensitivity = q[1, 1] / (q[1, 1] + q[2, 1]),
    specificity = q[2, 2] / (q[2, 2] + q[1, 2]),
    ppv         = q[1, 1] / (q[1, 1] + q[1, 2]),
    npv         = q[2, 2] / (q[2, 2] + q[2, 1]))
}))
```

Resulting in

```
final
#>      sensitivity specificity        ppv       npv
#> [1,]         0.0   0.5625000 0.00000000 0.8181818
#> [2,]         0.0   1.0000000        NaN 0.8000000
#> [3,]         0.2   0.5882353 0.06666667 0.8333333
#> [4,]         0.0   0.6923077 0.00000000 0.6923077
#> [5,]         0.5   0.6400000 0.25000000 0.8421053
```

---

However, it's nice to know why your own code didn't work, so here are a few issues that might be useful to consider:

1. You need factor columns rather than character columns for `confusionMatrix`
2. You were incrementing through the rows of `df`, but you need one iteration for each unique age, not each row in your data frame.
3. Your line to increment `x` happens outside of the `while` loop, so `x` never increments and the loop never terminates, so the console just hangs.
4. You are doing `if(x = df$Age)`, but you need a `==` to test equality.
5. It doesn't make sense to compare `x` to `df$Age` anyway, because `x` is length 1 and `df$Age` is a long vector.
6. You have unnecessary repetition by doing `q$table` each time. You can just make `q` equal to `q$table` to make your code more readable and less error-prone.
7. You call `matrix` at the end of the loop, but you don't store it anywhere, so the whole loop doesn't actually do anything.
8. You are trying to `rbind` an object called `matrix` in the last line which doesn't exist
9. Your lack of spaces between math operators, commas and variables make the code less readable and harder to debug. I'm not just saying this as a stylistic point; it is a major source of errors I see frequently here on SO.

Comment: Thanks so much for your thorough answer and explanation! I wasn't familiar with `sapply` so I did some reading on it. And I'm adding this comment for anyone else in the future, I also wanted to have a column that was labeled `Age` and listed the ages as rows, so I converted `final` into a dataframe and then did `setDT(final, keep.rownames = "Age")`.