# Compute sensitivity, specificity, and more using multiple input variables in R

Tags: r, automation, statistics, tidyverse, data-analysis

Preamble: the question I am going to ask can be considered a follow up of this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65298298/create-multiple-confusion-matrices-in-r-using-loops), for which a nice answer was provided. Also, I was given extremely helpful advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77614497/tidy-approach-to-assess-the-agreement-among-dichotomised-binary-parameters/77624116#77624116), and the idea of what I am dealing with now goes into a similar direction.

I am creating a largely automated dashboard and, therefore, look for ways to generalise whenever possible. Here, I have a dataframe (in the long format, work mostly done with packages from the tidyverse) with

- different methods (A, B, C, D, ...) called METHODEKURZ
- two different outcome values (0, 1) pertaining to METHODEKURZ, I call them CLASS_INT
- a set of comorbidities (COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5), sometimes more, sometimes less, called COMORB
- two different outcome values (0, 1) pertaining to COMORB, I call them VALUES

Based on this information, I would like to obtain an output that looks like this:

| METHODEKURZ | COMORB | Sensitivity | Specificity | PPV | NPV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | COM1 | 0.49 | 0.22 | 0.31 | 0.11 |
| B | COM1 | 0.31 | 0.22 | 0.22 | 0.49 |
| C | COM1 | 0.22 | 0.49 | 0.31 | 0.22 |
| D | COM1 | 0.49 | 0.22 | 0.31 | 0.11 |
| A | COM2 | 0.22 | 0.22 | 0.49 | 0.11 |
| B | COM2 | 0.49 | 0.22 | 0.31 | 0.22 |
| C | COM2 | 0.31 | 0.22 | 0.31 | 0.22 |
| D | COM2 | 0.31 | 0.22 | 0.31 | 0.49 |

If the question was solely to provide such an output with variable METHODEKURZ, the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65298298/create-multiple-confusion-matrices-in-r-using-loops) and rendered below would be adequate and has shown to work well:

```
library(tidyverse)

my_df <- structure(
  list(
    a = c('A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'), 
    b = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0), 
    c = c('COM1','COM1','COM1','COM1','COM2','COM2','COM2','COM2','COM3','COM3','COM3','COM3', 'COM4','COM4','COM4','COM4','COM5','COM5','COM5','COM5'),
    d = c(1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1) 
  ), 
  .Names = c("METHODEKURZ", "CLASS_INT", "COMORB", "VALUES"), 
  row.names = c(NA, 20L), 
  class = "data.frame") %>%
  mutate(across(c(contains('VALUES')), 
                ~as.factor(.))) %>%
  mutate(across(c(contains('CLASS_INT')), 
                ~as.factor(.))) 

t(sapply(sort(unique(my_df$METHODEKURZ)), function(i) { 
  
  q <- confusionMatrix(data      = my_df$CLASS_INT[my_df$METHODEKURZ == i],
                       reference = my_df$VALUES[my_df$METHODEKURZ == i])$table
  
  c(sensitivity = q[1, 1] / (q[1, 1] + q[2, 1]),
    specificity = q[2, 2] / (q[2, 2] + q[1, 2]),
    ppv         = q[1, 1] / (q[1, 1] + q[1, 2]),
    npv         = q[2, 2] / (q[2, 2] + q[2, 1]))
}))
```

However, I have COMORB as an additional variable, which I would love to be taken into consideration. Could anybody help me modify the code in a way to include COMORB as a variable? I will use the output as a table but will likely also invest some time into finding a good way to visualise it. Thanks a lot for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store each combination of variables into a data frame using `expand.grid` and compute the statistics using the values corresponding to each individual set of variables.

```
library(caret)

# Generate all the combinations of variables using expand.grid
var_combinations <- expand.grid("METHODEKURZ" = unique(my_df$METHODEKURZ), 
                                "COMORB" = unique(my_df$COMORB))

cbind(var_combinations, t(apply(var_combinations, 1, function(i) {
  set_of_rows <- my_df$METHODEKURZ == i[1] & my_df$COMORB == i[2]
  q <- confusionMatrix(data      = my_df$CLASS_INT[set_of_rows],
                       reference = my_df$VALUES[set_of_rows])$table
  
  c(sensitivity = q[1, 1] / (q[1, 1] + q[2, 1]),
    specificity = q[2, 2] / (q[2, 2] + q[1, 2]),
    ppv         = q[1, 1] / (q[1, 1] + q[1, 2]),
    npv         = q[2, 2] / (q[2, 2] + q[2, 1]))
})))

#   METHODEKURZ COMORB sensitivity specificity       ppv       npv
#1            A   COM1   1.0000000   0.6666667 0.6666667 1.0000000
#2            B   COM1   1.0000000   0.2500000 0.2500000 1.0000000
#3            C   COM1   0.3333333   0.5000000 0.5000000 0.3333333
#4            D   COM1   0.0000000   0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333
#5            A   COM2   1.0000000   0.0000000 0.6000000       NaN
#6            B   COM2   0.0000000   0.5000000 0.0000000 0.6666667
#7            C   COM2   1.0000000   0.5000000 0.3333333 1.0000000
#8            D   COM2   0.2500000   0.0000000 0.5000000 0.0000000
#9            A   COM3   0.5000000   0.0000000 0.2500000 0.0000000
#10           B   COM3   1.0000000   0.2500000 0.2500000 1.0000000
#11           C   COM3   0.3333333   0.5000000 0.5000000 0.3333333
#12           D   COM3   0.5000000   0.0000000 0.6666667 0.0000000
#13           A   COM4   0.6666667   0.0000000 0.5000000 0.0000000
#14           B   COM4   1.0000000   0.5000000 0.3333333 1.0000000
#15           C   COM4   1.0000000   1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
#16           D   COM4   0.5000000   0.3333333 0.3333333 0.5000000
#17           A   COM5   0.5000000   1.0000000 1.0000000 0.3333333
#18           B   COM5   0.0000000   0.7500000 0.0000000 0.7500000
#19           C   COM5   1.0000000   0.6666667 0.6666667 1.0000000
#20           D   COM5   0.5000000   0.0000000 0.6666667 0.0000000
```

---

**Raw data**

*I generated more values to get several observations for each combination of variables.*

```
library(dplyr)

#For reproducibility
set.seed(123)

my_df <- structure(
  list(
    a = rep(c('A','B','C','D'),length.out = 100), 
    b = sample(c(0,1),100, replace = TRUE), 
    c = c(rep('COM1',20),rep('COM2',20),rep('COM3',20),rep('COM4',20), rep('COM5',20)),
    d = sample(c(0,1),100, replace = TRUE)
  ), 
  .Names = c("METHODEKURZ", "CLASS_INT", "COMORB", "VALUES"), 
  row.names = c(NA, 100L), 
  class = "data.frame") %>%
  mutate(across(c(contains('VALUES')), 
                ~as.factor(.))) %>%
  mutate(across(c(contains('CLASS_INT')), 
                ~as.factor(.)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this kind and great help!